# auto-fill with minmax() when max-content has static value

Tags: css, css-grid

I'm tyring to understand the ability of auto-fill and auto-fit and I have a question.

With this code auto-fill tries to fill the space with the min value = 10px.

```
grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(10px, 1fr));
```

But when I try to make this line work auto-fill works with the max value = 100px.

```
grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(10px, 100px));
```

Shouldn't it still work with the min value?